# Change all commands in custom application menu on Debian

Tags: bash, debian, sudo, debian-wheezy

so what I have is applications that's supposed to run as root, what I want to do is to add a `sudo` in the beginning of each command with a single bash script, so I can run these programs directly from my applications menu, I have Debian-wheezy

Comment: Err, `sudo` is meant for the command line, not for GUI applications, you probably are asking about `gksudo` or `pkexec`. Anyways as you are planning it isn't going to work.

Comment: no it's for command line applications.